# ngRequired calling function on loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm using ngRequired to dynamically add a required value on a simple yes or no question. I'm invoking a function to return a boolean value, but for some reason the function is being called on a loop. I've removed the code being executed and replaced it with a `console.log`, thinking it maybe the due to the model being changed on every call but still the loop persists.

**Directive**

```
angular.module('ppApp').directive('questionContent', questionContent);

function questionContent() {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^^questionPanel',
        scope: true,
        template: '<div data-ng-include="questionTemplate"></div> ',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

            scope.someSelected = function (object) {
                if(object === undefined) { return }
                return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
                    return object[key];
                });
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
         <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkYes"
                   data-ng-model="validModel[question.title].yes"
                   class="form-check-input"
                   data-ng-required="!someSelected(validModel[question.title])"
                   data-ng-change=
                      "question.checkError(validModel[question.title].no);
                       isOptionValid(validModel[question.title].yes, question);"
                   data-ng-click="validModel[question.title].no = false"
                   required>
            <label for="checkYes" class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkNo"
                   data-ng-model="validModel[question.title].no"
                   class="form-check-input"
                   data-ng-required="!someSelected(validModel[question.title])"
                   data-ng-change="
                      question.checkError(validModel[question.title].no);"
                   data-ng-click="validModel[question.title].yes = false"
                   required>
            <label for="checkNo" class="form-check-label">No</label>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

Why is the function `someSelected` bring invoked by `ngRequired` on a loop?

Comment: What do you mean "on a loop"?  That template will cause the function to be called twice for one instance of <questionContent>, if there are more than one <questionContent> on a <questionPanel> or more than one <questionPanel>s then it will be called 2 * however many questions there are.

Comment: The function for some reason is being called in an infinite loop